# Identification Part Number electronic component

Tags: identification

What is the Part number of this component?

Top mark : B2

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: First guess: A SST5462 P-channel JFET; it has a "B2" marking. Many components have that marking, though. Any idea of the schematic it is in?

Comment: what is the component? ... are there any other markings that you see?

Comment: Possibly [ON Semiconductor BSV52LT1G](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Transistors-NPN-PNP_ON-Semicon_BSV52LT1G_ON-Semicon-ON-BSV52LT1G_C150223.html), [Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810301514_ON-Semiconductor-BSV52LT1G_C150223.pdf). The "U" would be a data code that can vary between parts. Can you measure it to at least determine type of device?

Comment: Thank you for your answers but no solution!
Several PN possible, no other information ...